# Custom 500 error page not working with JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a JAX-RS application deployed on JBoss AS 7.1.1.
In the web.xml file I configured custom error pages:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

It's working ok for 404 (no found) errors.
However, for 500 (internal server error), it doesn't work as expected:

- if my method throws an Exception, then my custom error page is displayed
- however, if I use in my method **return Response.serverError.build()**
  or **return Response.status(500).build()** then the default JBoss error page is displayed instead of my custom one!

How can I fix this?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

ExceptionMapper impl class catches the exception instead of letting the custom error page to be resolved from web.xml

The resolution would be to remove the ExceptionMapper impl class.