# Facelets custom error page - customize / wrap the exception message / stack trace

Tags: jsf, exception, facelets, stack-trace, custom-error-pages

I am using JBoss AS7.
I already know how to use my own `web.xml` error pages for HTTP Errors (e.g. 404, 500, ...) - thats not a problem.
But for debugging reasons I need to view the error StackTrace. How can I access the message that is shown by default and embed it in error page?

Comment: When you say "view the error stack trace" do you mean that you want to print it to the screen?

Comment: Thats exactly what i mean. But not on the console, but on the webpage (xhtml) for sure.

Comment: Have you investigated the JSF ExceptionHandlerFactory mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concrete exception instance is available as a request attribute with the name as keyed by [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_EXCEPTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_EXCEPTION) which has a value of [`javax.servlet.error.exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION).

Thus, this will give you the exception:

```
#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}
```

However, there's no standard facility to print its stack trace in the view. You'd need to [homebrew an EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174), something like as [JSF utility library OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) already has in flavor of `#{of:printStackTrace()}`. You can see it in action in the [OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler):

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
...
<li>Stack trace: <pre><code>#{of:printStackTrace(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'])}</code></pre></li>
```

whereby the function implementation look like this:

```
/**
 * Print the stack trace of the given exception.
 * @param exception The exception to print the stack trace for.
 * @return The printed stack trace.
 */
public static String printStackTrace(Throwable exception) {
    if (exception == null) {
        return null;
    }

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true));
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

#### See also:

- [What is the correct way to deal with JSF 2.0 exceptions for AJAXified components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components/)
- [What is the good approach to forward the exception from servlets to a jsp page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257928/what-is-the-good-approach-to-forward-the-exception-from-servlets-to-a-jsp-page/)

Comment: sounds good so far. While trying this, I recognized that actually my HTTP 500 Error custom page is not working at all.
Like in this posting (1), only my 404 page works. Are there any updates concerning the error 500 problem?

(1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694675/custom-500-error-page-not-working-with-jboss-as-7-1-1

Comment: Have you already read the [OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) as linked in my answer? It describes (and solves) many problems as to exception handling in JSF (ajax) requests.

Comment: great article - I got it to work now. Error 500 is being caught and the page contains the error message. thx.